# Firebase Crash Reporting - uploading custom files

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Is there a way to attach complete logcats to crashes using Firebase Crash Reporting?  I did notice that the Firebase SDK has some log functions, but those have to be specifically invoked.  My app already does a ton of logging to logcat using our own custom loggger (not Android logger) anyways, so I would hate to have to duplicate the log calls to Firebase.

For example, I would need to do:

```
MyLogger.d(TAG, "my log message");
Firebase.log("my log message");
```

Comment: Or you can include firebase logging in your custom logging so you don't have to duplicate code at call site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a complete logcat isn't really possible because modern Android permissions don't allow apps to access that any more (as logs could easily and accidentally contain sensitive information).  You will need to invoke the logging API to get logs attached.  It's advisable to hook your existing logging infrastructure to make this happen without duplication at every location.